# How can I disable GitLab Pages default domain when using a custom one?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

When using a custom domain for GitLab Pages (i.e. mysite.com), it seems that default domain (myaccount.gitlab.io/mysite) is also active, so content is published in both domains at once.

How can I disable default domain? If there is an option, I can’t find it.

I have looked into GitLab's documentation, forums and Googled it, but not found how to disable this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you can't because of the nature of how customDomain is implemented.
As stated in the doc https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/ the internal domain is a prerequisite even you use A handler with IP.